# Git URL difference gitolee@git.uip.co:inf5750/davidab/project_devidab and git.uip.co:inf5750/davidab/project_devidab

Tags: git

I have to tell someone a URL of my repository from a personal git Server.

I want to ask what is difference between these two in git. Are these both are considered same URL??

git.uip.co:inf/davidab/project_devidab

gitolee@git.uip.co:inf/davidab/project_devidab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is a difference between these 2 urls. 2nd one contains the username with which git is going to authenticate. Whether either of them would work would depend on the protocol you are using and the permissions you want to give the other user.

What protocol are you going to use? HTTP, SSH, GIT?

See here for explanations of the different protocols: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: I am using ssh key to authenticate